# How to secure PHP/JQuery/Ajax calls?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, session

I'm new to Ajax and PHP in general. So far, I managed to make an Ajax call to my PHP script which fetches data from my database. However, upon testing, I realized that, even if I'm not logged in, I can still access and run the PHP script directly and when that happens, it populates all the data from my table, which I don't want to happen.

Now based on that I see a major security issue where anyone can access and run the script and see user information.

Now I'm not familiar with security and stuff in PHP, kinda new to it. My question is how would I go about to make the script unaccessible directly, or only when the admin is logged in it could be accessible?

I read around that I could check the session, I tried but it didn't work for some reason. So I'll put what I coded below.

**Here's the PHP which fetches data, getData.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['name']) && isset($_SESSION['admin']) && ($_SESSION['admin']==1)){
        include_once('config.php');
        //Create PDO Object
        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        //Set Error Handling for PDO
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        //Query
        $sql = "SELECT users.name, users.email, users.admin, stores.admin, stores.name FROM users INNER JOIN stores ON users.id=stores.admin";
        //Prepare Statement
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo    '<td>'.$row[4].'</td>';
            echo    '<td>'.$row[0].'</td>';
            echo    '<td>'.$row[1].'</td>';
            echo    '<td>**********</td>';
            if($row[2] == 1){
                echo    '<td>Yes</td>';
            }elseif ($row[2] == 0) {
                echo    '<td>No</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        $con = null;
    }
?>
```

**Here's the ajax that does the call to get the data. It's just a snippet, but it's part of a bigger thing(button on click to be precise), myAjax.js:**

```
$.ajax({    //create an ajax request to getData.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "includes/getData.php",             
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){     
        $("#userInfo > tbody").html("<pre>"+response+"</pre>");
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

**Finally, this I set the following sessions, when user logs in:**

```
$_SESSION['id']
$_SESSION['name']
$_SESSION['admin']
```

> $_SESSION['admin'] == 1 means the user is an admin. Otherwise it's
>   not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Forgot to include what I tried to check the session. I update the PHP.

Thanks

Comment: "Now I'm not familiar with security and stuff in PHP, kinda new to it. My question is how would I go about to make the script unaccessible directly, or only when the admin is logged in it could be accessible?" — The same way as any other URL - authenticate the user and then check if they are authorised.

Comment: "I read around that I could check the session" — If you're using session based logins, then that will work. "I tried but it didn't work for some reason" — There's no sign of that attempt in the code you've shared.

Comment: All the php code that processes the ajax request could be encapsulated in an `if( $_SESSION['admin']==1 ){ /* code */ }` perhaps as one basic option

Comment: @Quentin I tried to put the PHP inside this `if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['name']) && isset($_SESSION['admin']) && ($_SESSION['admin']==1)){` and when I did that, no data would show. So I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @nTuply — So do some debugging. You're testing four different things but all in one go so you haven't established which of them is failing.

Comment: You have many loopholes in your approach. First of them is that you should not invoke whole Php script. You may want to use REST and call some API. Above that to make it more secure you may want to add token to each of request which would make it secure.

Comment: if you are using wordpress you can use nonce for verifying ajax call form verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do like this for checking whether the user is loged in or not to display the result or output

use `if(!empty($_SESSION['admin'] && $_SESSION['admin']==1 && !empty($_SESSION['name']) && !empty($_SESSION['id']))`

using !empty will also check that if the variable is set and has any value or not! using isset shows true even if the value of variable is "null". so It will pass the if conditions argument and show the result.

**One More thing:**

when you logout you need to unset the session variables using...

```
<?php
session_destroy();
session_unset();
```

this technique has worked always with me...thanks

Comment: Is empty is actually better than an if statement to check for nulls. I updated my code to this. Works perfect now. Thanks

Comment: See one more thing need to check, all the versions in shared hosting may not support empty function, for example godaddy, hostgator or bluehost etc...before making this project online just check for PHP version if it is 5.3 or more....thanks